# Endless Loop using vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, infinite-loop, v-for

Heyjo Fellow Coders, I hope y'all had a good start in the weekend.

I have a problem with my Vue2 (usind Vuetify 6.14.15) code. I am using data from my store, where I created cards to display buyable items. I wanted to add a delete button, to delete articles using this v-vialog and a v-for

```
<div class="mt-16">
  <v-list
  flat
  >
    <div
      v-for="(card, index) in $store.state.cards"
      :key="index"
    >
      <v-list-item>
        <template>
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-btn 
              icon
            >
            <v-icon>mdi-pencil</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </v-list-item-action>

          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>{{ card.name }}</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-action>
              <v-btn 
                icon
                @click="dialogDelete = true"
              >
              <v-icon color="red darken-1">mdi-delete</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </v-list-item-action>
        </template>
      </v-list-item>
      <v-divider></v-divider>
      <v-dialog
        v-model="dialogDelete"
        max-width="300"
      >
        <v-card>
          <v-card-title class="text-h5">
            sure to delete?
          </v-card-title>
          <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn
              color="error"
              text
              @click="dialogDelete = false"
            >
              no
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn
              color="error"
              text
              @click="deleteArticle(index)"
            >
              yes, delete
            </v-btn>
          </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
      </v-dialog>
    </div>
  </v-list>
</div>
```

the error I get in Chrome and Firefox is "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" so I guess I created an endless Loop here, but I can't figure out where.

Would appreciate any form of help, thank you in advance

Comment: this is a JavaScript Error, mostly caused by calling the same function recursively. look in console what function calls have filled the callstack, and find any references to that function that may have caused a recursive call. `v-for` has nothing to do with this type of error.

Comment: When I put the v-dialog outside of die div that contains my v-for it does work, so it has to be the loop or am I wrong?

Comment: I am new to this.. where do I find the callstack on console? I tried it this way: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/UI_Tour#call_stack
 but I dont know where to pause the debugger so it shows me the right callstack

Answer (score 1):

You should take the `v-dialog` outside of the `v-for` loop. See [issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/11479) on GitHub. You can store the selected-id-to-be-deleted in the component data, like `selectedId`, when the delete button is clicked and before opening the dialog (put them in a method instead of inline click action). Then clear it when dialog is closed or delete action is successful, up to you.